# MySQL ERROR 2026 - SSL connection error - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, django, ssl, centos, ubuntu-20.04

I've recently upgraded my local machine OS from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, I'm running my MySQL-server on CentOS (AWS). Post upgrade whenever I'm trying to connect to MySQL server it is throwing SSL connection error.

```sh
$ mysql -u yamcha -h database.yourproject.com -p --port 3309

ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol
```

But if I pass `--ssl-mode=disabled` option along with it, I'm able to connect remotely.

```
$ mysql -u yamcha -h database.yourproject.com -p --port 3309 --ssl-mode=disabled

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 22158946
Server version: 5.7.26 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

**Queries:**

> 1. How to connect without passing `--ssl-mode=disabled`
> 2. How to pass this `--ssl-mode=disabled` option in my Django application, currently I've defined it as shown below, but I'm still getting the same error.

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'yamcha',
        'USER': 'yamcha',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'HOST': 'database.yourproject.com',
        'PORT': '3309',
        'OPTIONS': {'ssl': False},
    }
```

Comment: The best solution would be to upgrade the version of mySQL being used in RDS. I have this issue with engine version `5.6.44` but not with `8.0.17` . TLS 1.0 is no longer considered secure so enforcing it to be used seems like a hacky solution to me.

Comment: @mRyan 's comment is the best answer and it worked for me

Answer (score 65):

Ubuntu 20 has improved the security level.
The only way i could connect was allowing the tls 1 .

Edit this file:

```
/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

And put at the beginning of file:

```
openssl_conf = default_conf
```

And in the end of that file too:

```
[ default_conf ]

ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]

system_default = ssl_default_sect

[ssl_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1
```

It help me a lot: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233186/ubuntu-20-04-how-to-set-lower-ssl-security-level

Comment: I did followed the steps and still the same issue, I'm only able to connect when I pass 
--ssl-mode=disabled

Comment: Where you 2 days ago ;-) Thx!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped me a lot

Comment: Instead of downgrading your ssl and potentially security level, you may also simply upgrade mysqld to ssl 1.2. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64971233) below.

Comment: this is a dangerous solution, TLS 1.0 has been deprecated due to significant security flaws. https://blog.cdnsun.com/tls-1-0-what-is-it-and-why-are-we-deprecating-it/

much better to upgrade your cryptography library to keep your database secure.

Answer (score 63):

For anyone googling, you can use this flag in `mysql` cmd:  `--ssl-mode=DISABLED`. I.E:

```
mysql -uuser -p'myPassw0rd!' -hmysql.company.com --ssl-mode=DISABLED
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer for me because I would not like to edit global settings to connect to a single SQL instance. This gives the perfect temp solution without affecting anything else.

Comment: I'm sure this isn't the ideal solution but is a quick way to get working as opposed to editing ssl confs

Comment: this advice completely disables ssl and conveniently puts the users password on the wire in plain text with no encryption. anyone who follows this advice should not be surprised when their mysql server is compromised. putting advice like this on stack overflow, without explaining the caveat of being completely insecure, is irresponsible at best.

Answer (score 14):

Add this to your mysql 5.7 server config file and then restart your mysql service

```
[mysqld]
tls_version=TLSv1.2
```

Now you should be able to connect to it using tls 1.2, which is the default in Ubuntu 20.04

---

For the sake of completeness, in Ubuntu 20.04 actually `my.cnf` and `mysql.cnf` are actually the same file. So editing either one will work.

```sh
$ readlink -f /etc/mysql/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf
```

Answer (score 9):

Bump `mysqlclient` to v2.X, which added `ssl_mode` option, https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/blob/main/HISTORY.rst

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'yamcha',
        'USER': 'yamcha',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'HOST': 'database.yourproject.com',
        'PORT': '3309',
        'OPTIONS': {'ssl_mode': 'DISABLED'},
    }
}
```

Comment: For me, just updating my version of `mysqlclient` did the trick. I did not change the DATABASES dict.

Comment: Thank you. This finally did it for me. It was impossible to find the documentation in the Django docs for what the option was actually called.

Answer (score 8):

If You are using MYSQL Workbench :

Just **Disable** the SSL by editing the connection.

1. Go to edit Connection in connection panel
2. Select SSL in options after parameter as given in screenshot
   On connection

[image]

3. Select Use SSL : NO

[image]

4. Finally it would look like this.

[image]

**On clients other than Mysql workbench also you can try disabling SSL**

Comment: Setting this option in workbench doesn't affect data exporting. It still fails with the same error.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want the upgraded security features then you can consider upgrading your mysql server to 5.7.

Answer (score 0):

I encoutered same question as well. Combine the idea from above and documents.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encrypted-connection-protocols-ciphers.html#encrypted-connection-supported-protocols

Here is my thought

1. Check os system openssl version and its support ssl/tls version by `$ openssl version`. Check the system settings `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` as well.
2. Check MySQL support TLS version by `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'tls_version';`
3. Check your python mysql client TLS version. For my experience I am using `mysql-connector-python`. Document said since 8.0.28 would not support TLS 1.1 and below. That's why I cannot connect to MySQL. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html

In MySQL document, it mentioned TLS version which client could use should be the union set of host os TLS version and MySQL TLS version.
For example, your host only support TLS 1.1 / 1.2 and MySQL setting si TLS 1.0.  There is no compatible TLS version for client.

Hope these tips could help.