# Airflow 2 - MySQL connection issue

Tags: airflow, mysql-connector, airflow-2.x

We have a MySQL task that is connecting to a 5.7.22 MySQL DB just fine in Airflow 1.10.15  using SSL (Extra: `{"ssl": {"ca": "ca.pem"}}` ).  However, once we upgraded to Airflow 2.0.2 the task fails with `(2026, 'SSL connection error: error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol')`.  Does anyone have any ideas about this behavior?

Below are the python packages for both before and after

Airflow 1.10.15

`mysqlclient==1.3.14`

Airflow 2.0.2

`mysql-connector-python==8.0.22`

`mysqlclient==2.0.3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might be because Airflow 2 uses a newer Debian which does not support TLS v1.

I am not 100% sure how you should configure your MySQL/Client but this sounds awfully similar to [MySQL ERROR 2026 - SSL connection error - Ubuntu 20.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61649764/mysql-error-2026-ssl-connection-error-ubuntu-20-04)

The solution is either to disable SSL (not recommended) or decrease security level of Debian (not recommended) or make sure that you use TLS v2

Apparently this can be done via changing your MySQL seetings and restarting it:

```
[mysqld]
tls_version=TLSv1.2
```