# MySQLdb.OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error: error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed')

Tags: python, ssl, sqlalchemy

I am interacting with a MySQL database locally and I am making a connection as show below:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from config import settings
import MySQLdb
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import mysqldb

connection = MySQLdb.connect(
    host=settings.DB_HOST,
    user=settings.DB_USERNAME,
    passwd=settings.DB_PASSWORD,
    db=settings.DB_NAME,
    autocommit=True,
    ssl_mode = "VERIFY_IDENTITY",
    ssl      = {
      "ca": "/etc/ssl/cert.pem"
    }
)


engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://", creator=lambda: connection, echo=True)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

Unfortunately when I run the application to establish a connection I get the error:

```
    connection = MySQLdb.connect(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/opium/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/walrus-zOf8itpX-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 121, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/opium/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/walrus-zOf8itpX-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error: error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed')
```

I am barely new to databases in general and the error is somehow related to ssl. How can I fix this issue:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL ERROR 2026 - SSL connection error - Ubuntu 20.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61649764/mysql-error-2026-ssl-connection-error-ubuntu-20-04)